# Removing certain list element on resize (desktop to mobile view)

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries

Is it possible to remove a few list elements when the site is resized to mobile view?

I have a horizontal menu in the navigation bar. Say, something like

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

On screen size above 768 pixels let the complete menu display as it is but once the size gets below 768 pixels I would want it not to show links 3 and 4.

In the css I tried

```
m-re { display: none; }
```

and added the class to the < li > element

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class = "m-re"><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class = "m-re"><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Did not work.

Comment: Can you demonstrate it *not* working ---because it should, assuming you *are* using media queries?

Comment: No, its not working. I tried. On resize it shows all 4.

Comment: Okay, sorry ... now it works. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without using classes if you want, try this

```
li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(4){
  display: none;
}
```

And then set a media query, for larger screens

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
    li:nth-child(3), li:nth-child(4){
        display: block;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/GwmbBb) you have a codepen!

Comment: Thank you Martin. I tried this for the past half an hour and it did not work ... after I ask for help on SO and then refresh my page ... it started working. Can, you please see David's answer and let me know which one is the better way of doing it ...

Comment: That depends, it's another way to do it, you have the option to not use classes, but if you want to do it will be ok too, another difference, I made this using mobile-first, that means, first you should make it work for mobile, and the for larger screens, here you have a good article about mobile first, https://getflywheel.com/layout/start-practicing-mobile-first-development/ , you can see the difference in the media query, he set a max-width, I set a min-width, it's up to you really.

Answer (score 2):

yes, exists the media-queries
this is the documentation https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp
However you can do

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .m-re{
    display:none
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Media queries would be helpful you could read about them over here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp